# jquery mobile pagecontainershow events binding correct way

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i have two pages in one file like so:

```
    <section id="firstpage" data-role="page">
    <header data-role="header">
      <h1>Event Example</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="ui-content">
      <p>This is page 1<a href="#secondpage">click here</a></p>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="secondpage" data-role="page">
    <header data-role="header">
      <h1>Event Example</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="ui-content">
      <p>This is page2</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

basically i want a pagecontainershow event to fire on secondpage show
what i want to do is that when the "secondpage" loads i want to perform run some initialization code. the problem i face is that the second page isnt active in the dom it is fetched by ajax so how do i bind events on the show of the second page

what i did is this

```
$( document ).on( "pagecontainershow", function ( event, ui ) {
var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "getActivePage" );
  if(activePage[0].id=="secondpage"){
   //do the initialization for second page
  }
  });
```

**the pagecontainershow show event is what i want but it fires for every page how can i bind it to fire on secondpage show only**

Comment: pagecontainershow is designed to fire for every page. you then use the ui.toPage to determine if the page of interest is being shown: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show

Answer (score 0):

I can just think of two alternatives, which I don't think would do any difference, but maybe worth trying:

1) use divs instead of sections

2) use the ui object to retrieve the current page  instead of the getActivePage method, like below:

```
$( document ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui) {
 var pageId = ui.toPage.prop('id');
 if(pageId ==='secondpage'){
  //do the initialization for second page
 }
});
```